# GLSL How to avoid multiple checking

Tags: opengl, if-statement, shader

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 120
uniform sampler2D sampler0;
uniform bool isf1;

vec4 f1(vec4 color) {
...
}
vec4 f2(vec4 color) {
...
}

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( sampler2, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    gl_FragColor = f1(gl_FragColor);
    if(isf1) gl_FragColor = f2(gl_FragColor); //How to avoid it?
}
```

texture resolution 1920x1080, so "if" calls 2073600 times and this is very inefficient. How to make 'if' fires only one time for all the texels?

Comment: How much longer does a frame take to render with that `if` in there?  1 millisecond?  1 second?  1 minute?

Answer (score 2):

Just switch textures between rendering whatever you render with `isf1` `true` and `false`. Switching textures is not *that* painful.

This absolutely reeks of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the only way to avoid the `if` in your shader is to have different versions of the program.

You mention in comments that there are actually six functions which might need to be called (perhaps you could add that info to your question). You could replace your `if`s with `#ifdef`s and generate (64?) versions of the program automatically (by prepending your code with the appropriate `#define`s).

The downside to this is that if you are drawing many different objects with different conditions, you have to switch shader programs between draws, which could be more expensive than the branches in the shader.

One thing to note is that branches are not too expensive (on more recent gpus) if adjacent fragments take the same path. In your case all fragments take the same path, so the branches are about as cheap as they can be.

Answer (score 0):

Compile two programs, one where `isf1` is `true` and one where it's `false`.

Use the appropriate program where you would have set the `isf1` uniform.

Comment: Unfortunately I have 6 functions, too many different combinations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196639/qt-multiple-qglshaderprogram-for-one-texture

Comment: @Dmitriy: Then you should have asked about *that* circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing some portion of code based on some outside variable that you pass in, ie that boolean `f1`. You should instead use subroutines. Set the subroutine in your OpenGL program based on `isf1` before you render, then render all of the things that "are f1". Repeat for things that aren't f1. This will select the proper functionality outside of the shader *once* instead of wasting clock cycles on every fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a little late, but I'd recommend taking a look at `subroutine` tutorial by Lighthouse3d [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/glsl-core-tutorial-subroutines/).

Furthermore, for more basic branches you can also optimize it using `clamp` and `mix`. [This tutorial](http://xissburg.com/eliminating-branches-in-shaders/) give a quite nice example.